# How can I take a list and append each element to a new list depending on its position?

Tags: python

So my first list created via a for loop looks like the following

```
["1variable1", "1variable2", "1variable3", "1variable4", "1variable5"].
```

I then want it to be appened to new list depending on their position.

```
so List1 will be [1variable1]
List2 will be [1variable2]
etc
```

Then the next step of the loop will create another

```
["2variable1", "2variable2", "2variable3", "2variable4", "2variable5"]
```

I then want to append that to the previous list to make;

```
List1 will be [1variable1, 1variable2]
List2 will be [1variable2, 2variable2]
etc.
```

At the moment I have it so that it simply used square brackets to pull out each part of the list but I don't know how to get this in a loop, maybe next time I run it there will be more than 4 entries and I will miss the 5th.

```
lst1 = [item[0] for item in Genres]
lst2 = [i[1] if len(i) > 1 else '' for i in Genres]
lst3 = [i[2] if len(i) > 2 else '' for i in Genres]
lst4 = [i[3] if len(i) > 3 else '' for i in Genres]
lst5 = [i[4] if len(i) > 4 else '' for i in Genres]
```

If the next list doesn't have as many as a previous list then it should fill in a blank space as they all need to be in the same position

The lists are created as follows;

```
my_list = my_list[1:]
length = len(my_list)
my_list =  my_list[0:3]
for film in my_list:
    filmIndex = my_list.index(film) + 1
    query = film + " imdb"
    for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=1, pause=2):
        page = requests.get(j)
        response = page.status_code
        if response == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
            genreData = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"subtext"})
```

Then

```
            for h in genreData:
                a = h.find_all('a')
                aLength = len(a)
                a1 = a[0]
                for b in range(0,aLength - 1):
                    r = a[b].string
                    genres.append(r)
```

I then want to add each genre into a seperate column, genre1, genre2 etc. up to how ever many max is. Obviously some of these mull be NULL if the max is 4 and one film only has 1
Then for each film will create a list of all the genres for that film and I want to put them into separate columns

Comment: You can always lust use ```len(List)``` to check how many entries are in that list

Comment: If you could "pad out" the lists, so that they are filled, and save them separately, you could do something like: `list(map(list, zip(lst1,lst2)))`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible method is to create a list of lists.

Creating a list of lists lets you iterate through the list to insert and place each variable into the list at the variable's index. Of course, if you've got a big list or are doing your first pass, you'll hit an index you haven't encountered yet, so you'll need to init an empty list at that index.

```py
list1 = ["1variable1", "1variable2", "1variable3", "1variable4", "1variable5"]
list2 = ["2variable1", "2variable2", "2variable3", "2variable4", "2variable5"]

biglist = []

#insert list1
#this for loop can be repeated for every list you want to enter - maybe 
#put those into a list of lists, too?
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
  #check to see if there's a list in this entry
  if 0 <= i < len(biglist):
    #there's already a list here, add this to it
    biglist[i].append(list1[i])
  else:
    #there's no list here yet, create one and add its first variable
    biglist.append([])
    biglist[i].append(list1[i])

#repeat for the second list, and so on - you can nest these
for i in range(0, len(list2)):
  if 0 <= i < len(biglist):
    biglist[i].append(list2[i])
  else:
    biglist.append([])
    biglist[i].append(list2[i])

for l in biglist:
  print(l)
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/GrotesqueLawngreenRoot)

Comment: Thanks for the help but surely you have just found a new way to get the same problem. You say "repeat for the second list, and so on." That is what I am trying to change. I don't necessarily know how many list will be created. I need a way to loop through "set" and apply each element to the new list dependiong on its position.

Comment: How are you getting the lists if you don't know how many are being created? Are they themselves being passed through a list? Or is a loop creating a list every time? Please post a bit of sample code so we can see exactly what we're up against.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited the original question

Comment: I then want to add each genre into a seperate column, genre1, genre2 etc. up to how ever many max is. Obviously some of these mull be NULL if the max is 4 and one film only has 1

Comment: Then for each film will create a list of all the genres for that film and I want to put them into separate columns.

Comment: Do you understand my issue now?